# What considerations go with SQL/CLR integration when database is live and changes are frequent?

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

I *just now* for the very first time made a CLR function and deployed it into a database, and after reading a little about how it works, think it's a good option for a C# programmer like me.

My question: if I press "control F5" and let VS do it's magic deploy of my user defined functions, etc, to my database -- what if there are current connections to that database using the previous version?

My hope is that it would be seamless.

If it would cause a query in progress to return an error, I have to wait until the time when a proper development environent can be used.

EDIT: I decided to put in what I'm going to use this for first based on feedback last time I posted with this tag.

I don't want to maintain logic in two languages, so I'm going to convert the following to C#:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tousd] 
(@Currency char(3), @Amount money)
RETURNS money
AS
BEGIN
declare @Return money
if(@Currency = 'USD')
    return @Amount * 1.0
else if(@Currency = 'EUR')
    return (@Amount * 1.3065)
else if(@Currency = 'GBP')
    return (@Amount * 1.5552)
else if(@Currency = 'CAD')
    return (@Amount * 0.9789)
else if(@Currency = 'AUD')
    return (@Amount * 0.9613)
else
    return 0.0
return @Return
end
```

Thanks in advance,
Aaron

Comment: Um, shouldn't something like this (where the actual factors are likely to vary on a regular basis) be table driven instead? I wouldn't expect to see the factors hard coded in either SQL or C#.

Comment: By table driven do you mean instead of hard coded multipliers I fetch them from a DB table?  Yes definately.  But would you do that in a completely different way, or would you have a function like this that make a lookup to another table?  I'm much better at writing C# code than TSQL, which is why I'm interested in the SQLCRR integration.

Comment: yes, I'd expect a table of multiplication factors. Once I've got that table, I'm not sure I'd bother with a function (there being so little to go in there). Being better at writing C# than SQL is not a good reason to translate working SQL into C# - it's a good reason to learn more about SQL. Generally, you'd look at using CLR in areas where TSQL is weak - for example, string manipulation.

Comment: i'm going to press the delete button on this since i've learned more about the topic since i posted and don't think it has much value

Answer (score 3):

Do not convert tsql to C# just becasue you are more comfortable with it. Databases are optimized to work best with SQL not C#. CLRs are only available to do things that SQL cannot do. If you can do it in SQl, do it in SQL.

Do not do any more work until you have a real dev environment. Mucking around with stuff people are actually using is unprofessional and dangerous to the data and can quickly lose your customers.

Comment: It's not unprofessional if you're doing things exactly the way your boss tells you to. PS - I don't want this thread to become opinionated or I won't get an answer :)

Comment: @Gabriel: then perhaps you should ask your boss what is the interaction between VS magic and existing users.